# Why doesn't this MySQL select query work with WHERE clause?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hello this is driving me crazy. I can't get this query to work with the WHERE clause. It works without it. I have tried everything. I have looked at dozens of websites and dozens of questions here. I can't see anything wrong with this query. But it gives me this error whenever I try to use a WHERE clause:

```
1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `cond` = '1'' at line 4
```

I have tried it with spaces and without, with single quotes and without, I have tried mysqli. I just can't figure out what the problem is.

Here is the code I currently have:

```
 $sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT *
    FROM `master_inv`
    ORDER BY `sku`
    WHERE `cond` = '1' 
SQL;
```

Comment: Actually, you have to check manuals *once more*.

Comment: where clause goes before order by

Comment: If you want to code your SQL out of order like that, I suggest looking into PDO or Active Record

Comment: It makes me wonder, why editor-badge-hunters always make error messages *harder* to read

Comment: Putting where clause before order by worked! Thanks! I thought I had tried that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**WHERE  clause goes before ORDER BY.**

```
$sql = <<<SQL
          SELECT *
          FROM `master_inv`
          WHERE `cond` = '1' 
          ORDER BY `sku`
         SQL;
```

Comment: @AlienWebguy This is the first question I've asked. I didn't notice the "accept" checkmark before. Thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL statement is out of order and your missing a select statement.

The ORDER BY statement should be placed after the WHERE clause

```
SELECT *
FROM master_inv
WHERE cond = '1'
ORDER BY sku
```

Answer (score 0):

It is just the order which is incorrect try:

```
SELECT *
FROM `master_inv`
WHERE `cond` = '1' 
ORDER BY `sku`
```

Comment: Don't grieve it so much. Actually, this question shouldn't be answered at all.